# Titanium Synchronization

Tags: android, titanium

i have problem to sync local image folder to server, i using titanium. When i run my program using android emulator, it works well. But when i try to run it using actual device, the program can not find the image file.

Below is my code. Please help.

```
$.btnfiles.addEventListener('click',function(e)
{
var dirTest = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory);
var dirList = dirTest.getDirectoryListing();
Titanium.API.info('Start loop for files length:' + dirList.length);
for ( i = 0; i < dirList.length; ++i){
    var f = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, dirList[i]);
    var data_to_send = { 
    "file": f.read(), "name1":Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory
    };
    xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
                             // function called when an error occurs, including a timeout
                             onerror : function(e) {
                                 //Ti.API.debug(e.error);
                                 alert('error');
                             },
                             timeout : 5000  // in milliseconds
                         });
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
                    xhr.open("POST","upload.php");
                    xhr.send(data_to_send); 

Titanium.API.info('Namef: ' + dirList[i]);

Titanium.API.info('Name: ' + i);
var file = Titanium.Filesystem.getFile(Titanium.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,dirList[i]);
if (file.exists()) { file.deleteFile(); }
} 
});
```

Comment: Hi, one question: what is in variables dirList, dirList[i] and f?

Comment: hi balaza. dirlist will return all the files that exist in the folder, so when i use dirList.length in for loop condition, actually it will return the number of files that exists. dirList[i] is to get the specific file in that listing.

Comment: sorry, I wasn't clear, my fault. What ACTUALLY is there in those variables? I mean, what can you see in console? 
You're complaining about different behaviour in device and emulator: are those value different or are them the same?

Comment: more: is it standard android emulator, or is it genymotion?